# how to split a string column in R based on equal length and get them in different rows

Tags: r, strsplit

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mydf

  V1    V2
2  1 abcdef
3  2   abcd
4  3   bghj
5  4   kl
6  5    uilm
```

I want to get my data frame that in result V2 column should be separated in the length of 2 in separate rows

```
   V1 V2
1   1  ab
2   1  cd
3   1  ef
4   2  ab
5   2  cd
6   3  bg
7   3  hj
8   4  kl
9   5  ui
10  5  lm
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option splitting the string every 2 characters -

```
mydf <- data.frame(V1 = 1:5, V2 = c('abcdef', 'abcd', 'bghj', 'kl', 'ulim'))

tmp <- strsplit(mydf$V2, '(?<=..)', perl = TRUE)
result <- mydf[rep(1:nrow(mydf), lengths(tmp)), ]
result$V2 <- unlist(tmp)
rownames(result) <- NULL
result

#   V1 V2
#1   1 ab
#2   1 cd
#3   1 ef
#4   2 ab
#5   2 cd
#6   3 bg
#7   3 hj
#8   4 kl
#9   5 ul
#10  5 im
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to sub-string every other character and apply it row wise on `V2` to create a nested column of character vector. Then, unnest the column.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- read.table(
  text = "
    V1    V2
  1 abcdef
  2   abcd
  3   bghj
  4   kl
  5    uilm",
  header = TRUE
)

get_string <- function(str) {
  n <- seq(1, nchar(str), 2)
  map_chr(n, ~ str_sub(str, ., . + 1))
}

mydf %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(V2 = list(get_string(V2))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  unnest(V2)

# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#       V1 V2   
#    <int> <chr>
#  1     1 ab   
#  2     1 cd   
#  3     1 ef   
#  4     2 ab   
#  5     2 cd   
#  6     3 bg   
#  7     3 hj   
#  8     4 kl   
#  9     5 ui   
# 10     5 lm
```

Answer (score 1):

Another tidyverse approach.  Basically it adds some extra character like `@` which may not be present elsewhere and then use `tidyr::separate_rows`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(V2 = map_chr(strsplit(V2, '(?<=..)', perl = T), ~paste(.x, collapse = '@'))) %>%
  separate_rows(V2)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>       V1 V2   
#>    <int> <chr>
#>  1     1 ab   
#>  2     1 cd   
#>  3     1 ef   
#>  4     2 ab   
#>  5     2 cd   
#>  6     3 bg   
#>  7     3 hj   
#>  8     4 kl   
#>  9     5 ul   
#> 10     5 im
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(V2 = list(str_sub(V2, seq(1, nchar(V2)-1, 2), seq(2, nchar(V2), 2)))) %>%
  unnest_longer(col = V2)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
      V1 V2   
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 ab   
 2     1 cd   
 3     1 ef   
 4     2 ab   
 5     2 cd   
 6     3 bg   
 7     3 hj   
 8     4 kl   
 9     5 ui   
10     5 lm
```